# Como pegar o codigo de um usuario via SESSION

Tags: php

Olá. Queria saber se isso é possivel

```
$nome=$_SESSION['nome'];
$codigoUsuario=buscaUsuario($nome);
inserirVenda($codigoUsuario,$codigoProduto);
```

Eu pego o nome dele via sessão passo pra uma variavel,faço uma busca no banco e retorno seu codigo para inserir ele em outra tabela no banco.  Esta acontecendo o seguinte erro.

**Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string**

aqui é onde eu pego as informações que foram mandadas do html.

```
   $nome=$_SESSION['nome'];
            $resultado2=buscaUsuario($nome);
            if($resultado2){
                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)){
                    $codigoUsuario=$linha['codigoUsu'];
                }
            }

            inserirVenda($codigoUsuario,$codigoProduto);
```

Esta dando um erro na função **inserirVenda**.

```
function inserirVenda($codigoUsuario,$codigoProduto){
    conectar();
    query("INSERT INTO venda (codigoProduto,codigoUsuario) VALUES ($codigoProduto,$codigoUsuario)");
    fechar();

}
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect_error() in C:\xampp\htdocs\igor_trabalho2\conexaoBD.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\igor_trabalho2\crudVenda.php(36): query('INSERT INTO ven...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\igor_trabalho2\controleVenda.php(26): inserirVenda('12', 'codigo') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\igor_trabalho2\conexaoBD.php on line 22**

Comment: Este erro indica que a forma como você está tratando a saída está errada. O mysqli_result retorna um objeto, não uma string, então não dá para somente mandar printar a variável, ela tem que passar por um laço de repetição primeiro para depois acessar os índices específicos do objeto. Poste mais do seu código!

Comment: realmente era isso. Mas agora esta dando um erro do banco